# When should I use os.name vs. sys.platform vs. platform.system()?

Tags: python, operating-system

There are at least three ways to detect OS/platform in Python.

What is the ideal application for each method? When should one method be used over another?

---

EDIT: My specific use case is install-time and and run-time checking of dependencies. I don't want to install certain libraries in `setup.py` if I'm on "Windows" because it will require Visual Studio. Then, at run-time I want to check if the dependency is available (which it might not be on "Windows").

EDIT 2: It would also be great to see a short example of when each level of OS detail is required.

Comment: One important question would be, why do you need to know?  Adding platform-specific behavior in Python is usually unnecessary.

Comment: @SteveHoward It could be for finding third party libraries, or user directories. It is oddity, considering Python encourages having one way to do things.

Comment: @SteveHoward my specific use case is install-time and and run-time checking of dependencies. I don't want to install certain libraries in `setup.py` if "Windows" because it will require Visual Studio. Then I want to check at run-time if the dependency is available (which it might not be on "Windows").

Comment: @LegoStormtroopr I just found that, but there is no accepted answer on that question and the highest voted does not clarify the use of `platform.system()`.

Comment: For me, `os.name => 'nt'`, `sys.platform => 'win32'`, and `platform.system() => 'Windows'`.

Comment: @SteveHoward Another possible option which I realised I'll use is including Windows7 specific windowing features (Live the live preview stuff) in an application.

Comment: @Doorknob ...but what should my Python library do with that information? (That's my question.)

Comment: I don't know, I really don't know much Python. Just pointing the difference between them out.

Comment: That question gives you the differences between the different calls. As for which one you *should* use, thats up to you and your application based on your need.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**It depends on how much information you need.**

[`os.name`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.name) will give you only a high-level idea of the environment you're on (e.g. POSIX vs. Windows NT) - not even an OS name. The documentation says:

> **See also** [`sys.platform`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html#sys.platform) has a finer granularity. [`os.uname()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.uname) gives system-dependent version information.
>   The platform module provides detailed checks for the system’s identity.

[`sys.platform`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html#sys.platform) gives you a little more information, and can actually tell you if you're running Linux vs. FreeBSD, for example.

The [`platform`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/platform.html#module-platform) module will give you the most information, down to the version of the operating system you're running under, and processor information.

So you should specify what exactly you're trying to accomplish, and then it will probably become clear which method is most appropriate.

Comment: I updated the question with my specific use case.

Comment: Just use whatever works. `os.name` will give you `nt` on Windows, and nowhere else. So if that's all you need then use that. Any more thought, and you're just wasting your time.